# Solve this query in use crosstab

Tags: sql, pivot, postgresql-9.1, crosstab

Here is my database table

```
| name |  |leave type|  |total lday|  |balance leave|  |balance|
|Nasrin|  |Annual    |  |3         |  |        14   |  |11     |
|labiba|  |Annual    |  |3         |  |        20   |  |17     |
|Zakir |  |Casual    |  |3         |  |        10   |  |7      |
|jabin |  |Earned    |  |3         |  |        14   |  |11     |
```

Now I want some modify in this query

```
| name |  |Annual|   |Casual|  |Earned| |balance leave| |balance|
|Nasrin|  |3     |   |0     |  |0     | |        14   |  |11     |
|labiba|  |3     |   |0     |  |0     | |        20   |  |17     |
|Zakir |  |0     |   |3     |  |0     | |        10   |  |7      |
|jabin |  |0     |   |0     |  |3     | |        14   |  |11     |
```

Comment: Use case expressions in the select list!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+pivot)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select 
   name, 
   max(case when leave_type='Annual' then "total lday" end) as Annual,
   max(case when leave_type='Casual' then "total lday" end) as Casual,
   max(case when leave_type='Earned' then "total lday" end) as Earned,
   balance leave,balance
from tablename
group by name,balance leave,balance
```